# Unable to upload web page

Tags: perl, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file from a web page.  I use CGI to query for all of the input fields but "my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("fileInput");" is always empty even when "my $file = $query->param("fileInput");" has properly fetched the file name from the same field.  Here is the code:

```
use CGI;

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
my $query = CGI->new;
my $url = $query->param("urlInput");
my $file = $query->param("fileInput");
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("fileInput");
my $text = $query->param("textInput");
my $k = $query->param("kInput");
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: How is your form defined? Does it have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Ahh, you are right!  I used to have an action for each input and now I have one action for all inputs.  The "enctype="multipart/form-data" got lost in the shuffle.  Will it be a problem to have that in a form elemenet that encompasses several input fields, only one of which is a file upload?

Answer (score 3):

I will repost my comment, as an answer:

- make sure your HTML form contains the `enctype` attribute, and that it's set to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`